# Dynamic element under the droppable parent, over and out event not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have 2 columns, i made these 2 columns as droppable, when i "over" on any one of them, I am creating new "list" as it's children, and I am making children's as well droppable..

But i am not able to drop on the new children, I require to append the dragged list element to children element..

here is my function i wrote :

```
 var generate = function (id) {

  var id = "#" + id, c = 0, ul = $("<ul />");

  $(id).empty();

    while(c < 10 ) {
      c ++;  
        ul.append($("<li />", { text : c + " new list"}));
    }

    return ul;

}


$("li").draggable({

    revert:true,
    helper: "clone"

});

$(".cl").droppable({
    accept: "li",
    activeClass : "highLight",
    over: function( event, ui ) {

       var elements = generate(event.target.id);

        $("#" + event.target.id).append(elements);

        $(".cl li").droppable({
            over : function (event, ui ){
                console.log("it is over now!"); // not working
            },
            drop : function () {
                console.log ("dropped");
            },

out : function () {
 console.log ("I am out") // not working..
}


            });

        }
    });
```

[Here is the live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3gwebtrain/3G9E7/4/)

Any one help me to sort this issue.. and new children became droppable and appending a copy of draggable list..?

Thanks in Advance..

Comment: Your Fiddle appears to work fine, I get the "dropped" logged within the console.

Comment: only the dropped event is working.. that not by droppable, that by draggable trigger.

Comment: I'm confused about what you mean, your draggable handler has no `dropped` event. Only the droppable handler has a `drop` event which is logging `dropped` in the console. What are you expecting to happen?

Comment: I am looking on about the "over" and "out" to work, properly on dynamic element..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you regenerating the top level children every time the mouse moves over the column. Fix it by adding this code at the top of your over: function:

```
if (event.target._generated)
    return;

event.target._generated = true;
```

Here is the working **FIDDLE**: http://jsfiddle.net/eM8CX/